# I am getting a pop-up in Sublime on save

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

[image]

I get this pop-up every time I save a .php file in sublime text 3. I have reinstalled sublime and uninstalled unused packages. What to do?

Error message: /bin/sh: php: command not found

Build 4143

Comment: What packages do you have installed? This looks like something has set up some sort of "lint on save" operation, but it can't lint because it can't find a `php` executable. You may need to configure a package to either point it toward your installation of PHP, or just turn off the "lint on save" option.

Comment: Thank you. It was a package called PHP Syntax Checker.